# Dividir base com o "for" no R

Tags: r, for

Como é o meu primeiro for no R encontrei dificuldade em aplicar essa função. Possuo uma base em que possui uma data base com diferentes anos e gostaria de dividir a base por datas bases.

A variável "data" possui data dividida desde Janeiro de 1995 (199501) até Março de 2017 (201703).

Com isso, tentei dividir da seguinte forma sem sucesso:

```
for(i in 199501:201703){
dados[i]<-
subset(dados,data==i)
}
```

Vocês sabem onde tem um bom material sobre essa função?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sempre que possível, evite usar `for` no `R`. É computacionalmente lento e que pode levar a cometer erros bobos. Por exemplo, fazer um `for` começando assim

```
for(i in 199501:201703)
```

vai te levar a considerar os meses 199501, 199502, ..., 199512, 199513, 199514 e assim por diante. Não é uma boa ideia.

Outro problema é salvar algo dentro de uma posição reservada para número (`dados[i]`) algo que tem duas dimensões (`subset(dados,data==i)`). Isto não vai funcionar. O ideal é salvar estes resultados dentro de uma lista. Além disso, tu estava tentando salvar novos objetos dentro do objeto antigo, criando assim uma receita para o loop não funcionar.

Assumindo que teu conjunto de dados se chama `dados` e ele tenha uma coluna com datas chamada `data`, uma maneira de resolver este problema utilizando `for` é a seguinte:

```
dadosLista <- list()

for (i in unique(dados$data)){
  dadosLista[[i]] <- subset(dados, data==i)
}
```

Isto vai gerar um pequeno inconveniente de que as primeiras 199500 posições da lista `dadosLista` serão `NULL`, e todas as posições que não tem um ano e mês correspondente, tipo 199533, serão NULL também. A vantagem é que o comando

```
dadosLista[[199803]]
```

vai retornar os dados para março de 1998. Dá pra remover os `NULL` rodando

```
dadosLista <- Filter(Negate(is.null), dadosLista)
```

O problema de fazer isto é que se perdem as referências com os índices dos anos e meses. Não há almoço grátis.

---

Entretanto, há uma solução melhor. Assumindo que teu conjunto de dados se chama `dados` e ele tenha uma coluna com datas chamada `data`, faça o seguinte:

```
dadosLista <- split(dados, dados$data)
```

Isto colocará os teus dados numa lista. Será possível acessar cada um dos conjuntos de dados separados através de comandos similares a

```
dadosLista$199501
```

Assim, cada posição da lista será identificada por um nome, idêntico ao ano e mês desejado, e não por um número. Vai deixar o código mais organizado, mais limpo e, acredito, rodar mais rápido do que se fosse utilizado um `for`.

Comment: Obrigado, Marcus. Acabei colocando minha base em uma Lista. Muito melhor mesmo como você falou.